# How do I relate the right/left form border?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

How do I relate the border of my form? How do I call it? Something like `form1.RightBorder`?

I already tried to create a `PictureBox`, put it in the right side and relate it, but after a few `PictureBox` controls my game started lagging.

Comment: My downvote until you put some effort to make your question **clear**. Now you may get 5 completely different opposite but right answers. See [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Anchor` property to anchor the control to a particular location.  So if you want it anchored to the bottom right, you could use:

```
pb.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
```

See the [Anchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) and [AnchorStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.anchorstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation for more info.